# GGplot Problems: Continuous values interpreted as discrete, cannot plot properly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been struggling to get this to work right for the last couple days and need your help. I have a variable which contains two lists, one character and one integer that looks like the following:

```
  TF_names         Rho_values 
1 AT1G09250 -0.033121027230011 
2 AT1G09250  0.131840177495553 
3 AT1G09250  0.114715426939286 
4 AT1G09250  0.175359740897296 
5 AT1G09250 0.0663759411918469 
6 AT1G09250 0.0310298439900796
```

There is a handful of TF names and rho values are from -1 to 1. All I want to do is plot these values along the x-axis (not on top of course) to see where they lie (aka do certain TF names have more high/low rho values). I have tried "cheating" by adding a y-value of -1 to keep them along a line, joining the vector to the right side of rho values and plotting with geom_point and geom_jitter, but in either case, the x-axis isn't based on rho.

The closest I've gotten is to this point is using the following code:

```
b <- ggplot(data=Col0_TF_5th_percent_reset) + 
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x=Rho_values, y = Set_y_axis, color=TF_names), 
              height = 0.1) + 
  ylim(-2,0)
```

And this gives me a plot that looks like:

[image: best Case Example Image]

It seems as though my x-values are being interpreted as being discrete (no idea why). The TF_names is a character type and the rho_values are integers. I tried to force the values as being continuous using `scale_x_continuous`, but I get an error:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

If anyone has any ideas, I am all open ears at this point. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The `Rho_values` shown are not integers (whole numbers). Most likely that column contains some non-numeric values and so was converted to character or factor when you read the data. It would help to see the code that generated the data frame and the result of `str(your_data_frame_name_here)`.

Comment: THANK YOU! Some of them were converted as factors (I can't tell by hand as there is too many values). I was able to figure out how to fix this by converting the factors to numeric values by: Col0_TF_5th_percent_reset$Rho_values <- as.numeric(levels(Col0_TF_5th_percent_reset$Rho_values))[Col0_TF_5th_percent_reset$Rho_values]

Comment: Just make sure you're getting the correct values back after conversion. Better approach is to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when reading the data.